# value changed class variables to JSON string

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I defined the following class:

'''

```
import { Deserializable } from '../deserializable';

export class Outdoor implements Deserializable {
    ActualTemp: number;
    TargetTemp: number;
    Day: number;


    deserialize(input: any): this {
        // Assign input to our object 
        if(input){
          Object.assign(this, input);
        }
        return this;
      }

    toJSON() {
      return Object.assign({}, this);
    }
}
```

'''

The toJSON function can generate a class data JSON String using

'''

```
const resource = JSON.stringify(this.appEngineMsg.Outdoor.toJSON());
```

'''

{"ActualTemp":60, "TargetTemp":55,"Day":23}

If I change the class object's variable this.appEngineMsg.Outdoor.TargertTemp, this.appEngineMsg.Outdoor.ActualTemp, then I would like to get the following JSON strings

{"Outdoor":{"TargetTemp":100}}

{"Outdoor":{"ActualTemp":100}}

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, do you want to print 2 differents JSON objects for each property?

Comment: Yes, I would like to send out multiple JSON strings base on how many changed variables

Comment: I think the question isn't clear about this. What you really want is to 'observe' the changes, in this case i suggest using [rxjs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html), just change the fields to be observable and use getters and setters on it. You'd also have to change the actual JSON functions.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to solve two problems. 1) Detect value changes 2) generate the JSON string like {"TargetTemp":100} for individual variables in the class. I could generate class object JSON string using toJSON() function. How to generate the JSON string for a single variable of a class in a better way? I thought about defining functions like getTargetTempJSON() then format the string using hard-coded variable name "TargetTemp", but this will be too much code to write if I have a class with hundreds of variables